# Working with multiple linear layouts and weights

Tags: android, xml

[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZj55.png)

I am having difficulties achieving a layout in Android Studio that looks something like that in the attached image. I don't want to specify the heights and weights in terms of dp as I'd like the layout to fill the width of any parent it may be displayed on, but I am unsure how to go about specifying the weights for each linear layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but with the usage of weights you can achieve that.

With a layout like this, you could handle having images on the side and textView or editTexts in the middle:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="abc"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="def"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to use multiple linearlayouts you can add the other parts of your desired result into seperate layouts.